# Multi-platform solution to using fprintf to print to both console and file

Tags: c++, file, console, printf, multiplatform

I'm running an OpenGL program, and have setup a basic error reporting system which I'm using to call a function which uses `fprintf` and prints to `stderr`. On top of this, I have several `fprintf`'s inline with the rest of my code.

I also have a `fstream` setup which allows me to print directly to the log file of my choice. However I don't want to duplicate every line in which I use `fprintf` to include printing to the log.

Is there a way I can set my `stderr` and `stdout` to also point to the log, or can I create my own?

I'm seeing other questions like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637503/printf-to-both-console-window-and-file) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978480/using-freopen-to-print-to-file-and-screen), and the answers seem to use a `tee` and `wtee` function. The second one states that `tee` only works on UNIX. Since I'm doing this on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows, so this isn't going to be an option. However I *am* trying to cross-platform my application, so I'm looking for a cross-platform solution. I'm not too worried about Linux at this stage, as long as it works on MacOS and Windows.

Comment: There's no such facility - one file descriptor writing to two files - on Linux; as such, the short answer is: nope.

Comment: You could use `sprintf` to create a string, then output that to both/all file handles.

Comment: just make your `my_pretty_log_function(const char *fmt, ...)` that wraps `vsprintf` and forwards the formatted output to as many streams/facilities as you wish.

Comment: @Serge I was going to do that, but I also have them lying around everywhere else in the file which I can't afford to use the function for.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Can you please provide an example? I don't understand.

Comment: char buf[BIG]; sprintf_s(buf, "format", parameters); fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf); fprintf(log_file, "%s", buf);  Alternatively you could use fwrite instead of fprintf, or construct `std::string` objects with your messages.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This is the issue I'm having. I don't want to need to use two different lines. One for the console and one for the log. I want to be able to use a **single** command to print to both.